# Why is Clip (coverage) in ArcMap not working?

Tags: arcmap, clip, esri-coverage-format, arcinfo-workstation

Clip Analysis and Clip Data Management work fine, but I cannot open the tool or the help menu for Clip Coverage.

Does this sometimes happen because the tool requires an extension to run?

Comment: Do you have ArcInfo Workstation installed?  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-coverage-toolbox.htm >> `If you do not have ArcInfo Workstation installed, the Coverage toolbox will not appear in the list of available toolboxes.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are using the coverage format that was developed in the early 1980s for ARC/INFO, which became known as ArcInfo Workstation after the release of ArcGIS in 1999, there should be no need to use the Coverage Tools.

Answer (score 0):

The Coverage Tools in ArcToolbox can only be used with data in the ArcInfo Coverage format.